# Execute dynamic query with IF-ELSE statements and sp_executesql command

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql, sp-executesql

I have created the following table using the SQL Server

```sql
CREATE TABLE test 
(
     id_number NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     number_of_products NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test (id_number, number_of_products)
VALUES (1000077004, 3),
       (1000077005, 4),
       (1000077006, 4),
       (1000077007, 5),
       (1000077008, 5),
       (1000077009, 6);
```

And I have also created a custom procedure using dynamic SQL to run a custom-oriented query

Procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_dynamicquery1]
    (@TableName NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
     @Field     NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
     @Criterion NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
     @Parameter NVARCHAR(100) = NULL)
AS          
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;  
 
    DECLARE @SQL          NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @ParameterDef NVARCHAR(500)
    DECLARE @all          VARCHAR(2) = '-1'

    SET @ParameterDef = '@TableName NVARCHAR(50),
                         @Field     NVARCHAR(100),
                         @Criterion NVARCHAR(100),
                         @Parameter  NVARCHAR(100)'

    SET @SQL = 'SELECT *
                FROM TableName
                WHERE Field Criterion Parameter'

    SET @TableName = CASE 
                        WHEN @TableName IS NOT NULL AND @TableName <> 0
                           THEN SET @SQL = @SQL+ ' AND TableName = @TableName'
                           ELSE  '''' + @all + ''' = ''' + @all + ''''
                     END

    SET @Field = CASE 
                    WHEN @Field IS NOT NULL AND @Field <> 0
                       THEN SET @SQL = @SQL+ ' AND Field = @Field'
                       ELSE  '''' + @all + ''' = ''' + @all + ''''
                 END

    SET @Criterion = CASE 
                        WHEN @Criterion = 'greater than'
                           THEN SET @SQL = @SQL+ ' AND Criterion = >'
                        WHEN @Criterion = 'greater than or equal'
                           THEN SET @SQL = @SQL+ ' AND Criterion = >='
                        WHEN @Criterion = 'less than'
                           THEN SET @SQL = @SQL+ ' AND Criterion = <'
                        WHEN @Criterion = 'less than or equal'
                           THEN SET @SQL = @SQL+ ' AND Criterion = <='
                        WHEN @Criterion = 'equal'
                           THEN SET @SQL = @SQL+ ' AND Criterion = ='
                        WHEN @Criterion = 'not equal'
                           THEN SET @SQL = @SQL+ ' AND Criterion = <>'
                        ELSE  '''' + @all + ''' = ''' + @all + ''''
                     END

    SET @Parameter = CASE 
                        WHEN @Parameter IS NOT NULL AND @Parameter <> 0
                           THEN SET @SQL = @SQL+ ' AND Parameter = @Parameter'
                           ELSE  '''' + @all + ''' = ''' + @all + ''''
                     END

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL,  
              @ParameterDef, 
              @TableName = @TableName, @Field = @Field, @Criterion = @Criterion, @Parameter = @Parameter
END
```

Briefly, I will explain what my procedure does:

- Step 1: Takes as input 4 parameters (`TableName, Field, Criterion, Parameter`)
- Step 2: Sets a query to select all values based on a sample criterion (greater than, less than, etc)
- Step 3: Runs 4 if-else statements to define the value of each variable. Basically, if the user gives a value then the parameters takes that value, else the parameter takes the value '-1' (@all)
- Step 4: I execute the command  `EXEC sp_executesql` to complete my query dynamically

When I try to create the procedure I get following errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure usp_dynamicquery1, Line 45 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure usp_dynamicquery1, Line 46 [Batch Start  Line 0]
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure usp_dynamicquery1, Line 51 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'.

Expected result when I run the query below:

```sql
[usp_dynamicquery1] @TableName='test', @Field='number_of_products', @Criterion='greater than', @Parameter = '4'
```

Return the id_numbers with number_of_products > 4 (thus the last three rows of the test table).

Comment: `case` is an **expression** not a statement, as as such can only return a value, not run a statement. You need to rewrite them all to return values.

Comment: @DaleK thank you for your comment. As I am a new user of SQL can you please provide an example highlighting your solution based on my CASE WHEN scenario? It would be very helpful to know the correct syntax. Thank you.

Comment: Please consult the [Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) I don't know your logic well enough to rewrite it for you.

Comment: In your SET \@SQL statement you haven't included the value of the parameters, you should have something along these lines SET \@sql = N'SELECT * FROM ' + @table;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea and are headed in the right direction. I figured I'd give you a hand to help you learn how I would approach this.

Here is my version of your stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_dynamicquery1] (
    @TableName NVARCHAR(50),
    @Field NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @Criterion NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @Parameter NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @All VARCHAR(2) = '-1'
)
AS          
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;  
 
    DECLARE 
        @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @SQL_WHERE NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @ParameterDef NVARCHAR(500);

    SET @ParameterDef = '@Parameter NVARCHAR(100)'
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @TableName;
    SET @SQL_WHERE = '';

    /* BUILD THE WHERE CLAUSE IF @Field IS PRESENT */

    IF NULLIF ( @Field, '' ) IS NOT NULL BEGIN

        -- Field.
        SET @SQL_WHERE = ' WHERE ' + @Field;

        -- Field Comparison.
        SET @SQL_WHERE += CASE @Criterion 
            WHEN 'greater than' THEN ' >'
            WHEN 'greater than or equal' THEN ' >='
            WHEN 'less than' THEN ' <'
            WHEN 'less than or equal' THEN ' <='
            WHEN 'not equal' THEN ' <>'
            ELSE ' ='
        END;

        -- Field Parameter.
        SET @SQL_WHERE += ' @Parameter';

        -- Set @Parameter value.
        SET @Parameter =
            CASE WHEN NULLIF ( @Parameter, '' ) IS NOT NULL
                THEN @Parameter
                ELSE @All
            END;

    END

    -- Finish SQL statement.
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ISNULL ( @SQL_WHERE, '' ) + ';';

    -- Execute the dynamic statement.
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @ParameterDef, @Parameter = @Parameter;

END
GO
```

A few quick things worth noting:

- `@TableName` *must* be required, otherwise, what do you intend to query?
- The `WHERE` clause is only constructed if `@Field` is present.
- Shortened the `@ParameterDef` variable to include `@Parameter` only. The rest of the t-sql is formed prior to calling `sp_execute_sql`. I left @Parameter so that you wouldn't have to worry about single ticks around values, etc.
- Added `@All` as a `DEFAULT`ed parameter (-1) to the SP to the value can be changed if wanted.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, it works as expected. To summarize your approach, you basically create an empty SQL_WHERE and then you construct the statement based on @Field, @Criterion and @Parameter. You also mentioned that @TableName is required. Where you define this? Maybe in the sql statement ```SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @TableName;``` ?

Comment: @NikSp I simply changed your SP's signature from `@TableName NVARCHAR(50) = NULL, ...` to `@TableName NVARCHAR(50), ...`. By removing the DEFAULT of NULL, anything that calls the SP will have to provide a value for @TableName.